# Manipular arquivo .txt e colocá-lo em um array em Ruby

Tags: ruby

Preciso que, a partir de um arquivo .txt que possuí vários tweets (um em cada linha), ler esse arquivo e colocar em uma variável no seguinte formato:

```
[1, "texto da primeira linha do arquivo"], [1, "texto da segunda linha"]
```

Eu consegui ler o arquivo e imprimi-lo, mas não consigo montar o vetor de arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`readlines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-readlines)

```
tweets = IO.readlines('filename.txt')
puts tweets[0] # => "primeiro tweet"
```

Mas se você quiser um array idêntico ao que você pediu, faça assim:

```
tweets = IO.readlines('filename.txt').each_with_index.map do |line, line_num|
  [line_num, line]
end
puts tweets[0] # => [0, "primeiro tweet"]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Só uma breve dúvida. O que significa o .map?

Comment: O [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) é muito comum em linguagens de programação, e o que ele faz é retornar cada execução do bloco dentro de um array. Por exemplo: `[1, 2, 3].map {|number| number * 2 } # => [2, 4, 6]`

Comment: Entendi! E qual a diferença para o .each?

Comment: O each não retorna nada, usando o exemplo anterior: `[1, 2, 3].each {|number| number * 2 } # => [1, 2, 3]`. Para você reproduzir o resultado do `map` usando o `each` vc teria que fazer + ou - assim: `tmp = []; [1, 2, 3].each {|number| tmp << number * 2 }; puts tmp # => [2, 4, 6]`. Veja mais aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas (: